# Accessing Flash content website through Citrix Xenapp 6 Published IE9 is not working

Tags: internet-explorer, flash

I am looking for assistance to the below issue ,

Non Administrator Users are trying to access Flash content website using IE9 which is published through Citrix (Xenapp6.0). The login page comes back after entering credentials.

This does not happen for all users, few users are able to login while others are not.

checked on multiple things and found the below behaviour:

The Flash Cache directory "\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player#SharedObjects" is created for the users who is able to login to the Site.

However this folder is not created for users who are unable to login and have issues.

Product Details on the Citrix Server:

Windows 2008 R2 64bit

XenApp 6.0

IE 9

Flash Player 11

Adobe Reader 10

Java Version 7

Any suggestions on this would greatly help

Comment: Any update on my query?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could help:

ADOBE FLASH PLAYER NOT WORKING ON CITRIX SERVER FOR NON ADMIN-ISTRATORS

Ran into a real fun problem today where we needed to upgrade the flash player to the latest version on our Citrix Farm. Installed Adobe Flash Player on both servers, and tested it out. Worked fine. When our users (non-admins) logged in they ran into issues with the activeX installer popping up, after clicking install – no progress was made, page would not load flash correctly. One would think to edit Group Policy and allow activeX, but in this case the answer resides elsewhere.

Here’s the fix (Courtesy of Brian Madden):

1. Open regedit
2. Go `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOTTypeLib{D27CDB6B-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}]` and right-click, change the permission to Read for “Everyone”
3. Go `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOTCLSID{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}` and right-click, change the permission to Read for "Everyone"
   Note: In Brian Madden's forum, Simon refers to the CLSID entry `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOTCLSID{D27CDB6B-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}]` but this was not present on my server. In any event, if you find yourself up against the same issue browse the registry, start in the “D27″ section of the above mentioned areas, and be sure to look on the right-hand side. When you see “Shockwave Flash Object”, that’s it. Change the permission to read.

Now ask you users to logout and back in. They should be able to access their flash enabled websites now with no issues.